Jest open handles with supertest get
I'm testing a POST and GET endpoint with supertest. My test fails to exit cleanly. However, when I run --detectOpenHandles, the script just hangs with no print output. Additionally, if I comment out the GET, the script exits cleanly.
I'm looking for insigt and debugging next steps.
The relevant code is included below:
import { app } from '../main';
import { get, post, put, deleteHTTP } from '../auth_http';
import { assert, log } from 'console';

import gremlin from 'gremlin';
const {
  cardinality: { single },
} = gremlin.process;
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;

import { after } from 'node:test';
import { GremlinID } from '../models/id';

jest.setTimeout(30000); // Timeout of 30 seconds for all tests in this file

const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;
let dc: gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
let g: gremlin.process.GraphTraversalSource<gremlin.process.GraphTraversal>;
const {
  t: { id },
} = gremlin.process;

let users: any[] = [];

beforeAll(async () => {
  // set up db
  const sevennURL = `wss://neptunedbcluster-r8443xcctbxv.cluster-cn8gbugm7fpg.us-west-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin`;
  dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(sevennURL, {}); //prodd
  const graph = new Graph();
  g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);

  let user1 = await g
    .addV('user')
    .property('test', true)
    .property(id, '1')
    .property('firstName', 'Jeremy')
    .next();
  let user2 = await g
    .addV('user')
    .property('test', true)
    .property(id, '2')
    .property('firstName', 'Jane')
    .property('phoneNumber', '+16505551235')
    .next();
  let user3 = await g
    .addV('user')
    .property('test', true)
    .property(id, '3')
    .property('firstName', 'Bob')
    .property('phoneNumber', '+16505556789')
    .next();
}, 60000);

afterAll(async () => {
  // drop test users
  await g.V().hasLabel('user').has('test', true).drop().next();
  // Close the graph connection
  await dc.close();
});

beforeEach(async () => {});

afterEach(async () => {});

describe('/users/contacts', () => {
  it.only('should succesfully get contacts', async () => {
    const res = await post('/users/contacts', app).send({
      userId: '1',
      contacts: [
        { phoneNumber: '+16505551236', firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
        { phoneNumber: '+16505551235', firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' },
      ],
    });

    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);

    await process.nextTick(() => {});
    const contacts = await get('/users/contacts?userId=1', app).send();
    log(contacts.status);
    expect(contacts.status).toEqual(200);
    // log('contacts data: ' + contacts.data);
  });
});


const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('./main');
const express = require('express');
import { log } from 'console';
// import your Express app or server

export let get = (url: String, app: Express.Application) => {
  return request(app).get(url).set('Authorization', 'redacted');
};

export let post = (url: String, app: Express.Application) => {
  return request(app).post(url).set('Authorization', 'redacted');
};

export let put = (url: String, app: Express.Application) => {
  return request(app).put(url).set('Authorization', 'redacted');
};

export let deleteHTTP = (url: String, app: Express.Application) => {
  return request(app).delete(url).set('Authorization', 'redacted');
};


router.get(
  '/users/contacts',
  asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const g = req.g;

      const { userId, excludeSevennUsers }: { userId: string; excludeSevennUsers: string } =
        req.query as any;

      if (!userId) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'userId is empty' });
      }

      let userExists = await g.V(userId).hasLabel('user').hasNext();

      if (!userExists) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "user doesn't exist in db, userId: " + userId });
      }

      let query = g.V(userId).outE('HAS_CONTACT');

      if (excludeSevennUsers) {
        query = query.where(__.inV().not(__.hasLabel('user')));
      }

      query = query
        .dedup()
        .project('id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'photoUrl')
        .by(__.coalesce(__.inV().id()))
        .by(__.coalesce(__.inV().values('firstName'), __.values('firstName'), __.constant('')))
        .by(__.coalesce(__.inV().values('lastName'), __.values('lastName'), __.constant('')))
        .by(__.coalesce(__.inV().values('photoUrl'), __.constant('')));

      let contacts = await query.toList();

      contacts = contacts.map((contact: any) => Object.fromEntries(contact.entries()));

      return res.status(200).json({ contacts: contacts });
    } catch (err: any) {
      log('error in /users/contacts: ' + err);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'error in /users/contacts: ' + err });
    }
  }),
);

